# Regular expression for laravel route

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-routing

I want to make a regular expression for this laravel route.

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@profile')
```

So far I was able to accept number only and string only using `->where('id', '\w+');` and `)->where('id', '\d+');`

But, I would like to make the rule so it accepts strings from `0-9`, hyphen `-` and any string from `A-Z` or `a-z`

How can I do this. I haven't done any regex before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is: `[0-9A-Za-z\-]+`

Comment: Nope. It didn't work. `Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@profile')->where('id', '[0-9A-Za-z\-]');`

Comment: Try adding the `+` character in the end.

Comment: It seems to work. I will accept it in 5 minutes. One more question, what rule would I need to make it so, that it does not start with `-` ?

Comment: Try this: `[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z\-]*`